# How to fixed the error when the code results Error 9 while creating new Excel File

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to create a new file and save the new file, however when i run the code, Error 9 pops up.

```
Sub openwba()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim NewWB As String
NewWB = "C:\Users\Chengwu\Desktop\Train10_June01.xlsx"

Set wb = Workbooks.Add
wb.SaveAs Workbooks(NewWB)

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `wb.SaveAs` is wrong. Try: `wb.SaveAs Filename:=NewWb`

Comment: You should specify what the error message says and not just the number. In this case it is a subscript out of range error, raised because `NewWB` is not the name of an existing workbook in the workbooks collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim wk As Workbook
    Dim NewWB As String

    If Dir("C:\Users\Chengwu\Desktop\Train10_June01.xlsx") = "" Then

        NewWB = "C:\Users\Chengwu\Desktop\Train10_June01.xlsx"
        Set wk = Workbooks.Add
        wk.SaveAs Filename:=NewWB

    End If

End Sub
```

Note:

- Take the necessary safeguards in order to avoid error in case of file already exist.